# Hibernate spatial jpa query not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-spatial

I have written spatial query to find nearest point from a location. But hibernate get exception. **My Application with Spring boot 1.5.7**

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface PlaceRepository extends JpaRepository<PlaceEntity, Long> {
    PlaceEntity findByCode(String code);
    PlaceEntity findByName(String name);
    @Query("select l from PlaceEntity l where within(l.location, :filter) = true")
    List<PlaceEntity> findLocationWithin(Geometry filter);
}
```

Here my entity class param

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Place")
public class PlaceEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "LOCATION",columnDefinition = "POINT")
    private Point location;
}
```

Others Params are

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "CODE")
private String code;
@Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
private Double longitude;
@Column(name = "LATITUDE")
private Double latitude;
```

Here my build.gradle.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.0.Final')
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:4.3")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.0.Final")
compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

Configuration

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

}
```

But when I deploy server then get exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pathController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pathService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pathServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'placeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fm.assignment.core.dao.PlaceRepository.findLocationWithin(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pathServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'placeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fm.assignment.core.dao.PlaceRepository.findLocationWithin(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:58


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'placeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fm.assignment.core.dao.PlaceRepository.findLocationWithin(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fm.assignment.core.dao.PlaceRepository.findLocationWithin(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PlaceEntity is not mapped [select l from PlaceEntity l where within(l.location, :filter) = true]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)



Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PlaceEntity is not mapped [select l from PlaceEntity l where within(l.location, :filter) = true]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)




Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PlaceEntity is not mapped
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
```

**Is there any mistake from my configuration?**

Comment: show the Configuration spring class and also the entity class definition with annotations

Comment: I Updated Question body. Please check.

Comment: Please add the complete `PlaceEntity` code.

Comment: I added PlaceEntity. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your entity **Place** (`@Entity(name = "Place")`) but you still use **PlaceEntity** in your jpql query.

Try it like this;

```
select l from Place l where within(l.location, :filter) = true
```

Or keep using `PlaceEntity` in your queries and use following annotations;

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name ="Place")
public class PlaceEntity extends BaseEntity {}
```

Answer (score 2):

in future use variables in spring-data-jpa repositories like **#{#entityName}** to safe yourself from such errors

```
@Query("select l from #{#entityName} l where within(l.location, :filter) = true")
```